# How do I comma separate zero padded String.format doubles in java?

Tags: java, number-formatting

I am trying to use String.format for get comma separated, zero padded doubles.
I am using:

```
"%0,9.2f", unitPrice
```

Unit price is a double. When unitPrice is, for example, 44.99 I get 000044.99 when I want 00,044.99. If unit price is 4499 instead I get 04,499.00 as wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) (a *concrete subclass of `NumberFormat` that formats decimal numbers. It has a variety of features designed to make it possible to parse and format numbers in any locale, including support for Western, Arabic, and Indic digits*) like

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00,000.00");
System.out.println(df.format(44.99));
System.out.println(df.format(4499));
```

Output is (as requested)

```
00,044.99
04,499.00
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible for values equal or larger than 1000. Checked the source code of Java 8 and the *zero padding* is done after *inserting group separators*.

You have to write your own format like the answer from @Elliot Frisch.

Note that his answer is Locale dependent, but you can force the comma `,` by providing a localized instance of DecimalFormatSymbols.

```
new DecimalFormat("00,000.00", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.US))
```

Comment: Thanks for the added explanation, localization isn't a concern right now, this is mostly for my own learning.